# POSTGRESQL: query optimization

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I have a query that I cannot optimize:

```
SELECT evse_label AS evse_label,
evc_model AS evc_model,
address AS address,
city AS city,
message AS message,
reason AS reason,
min(timestamp) AS oldest_timestamp,
max(timestamp) AS latest_timestamp,
count(message) AS "# messages"
FROM public.om_logbook_mart
GROUP BY evse_label,
evc_model,
address,
city,
message,
reason
ORDER BY oldest_timestamp DESC
LIMIT 10000
```

I tried to create the following index:

```
CREATE INDEX evselabel_evc_model_address_city_reason_message_timestamp_idx
ON om_logbook_mart (evse_label,evc_model,address,city,message,reason,timestamp);
```

Unfortunately nothing changes and the query still lasts around 40s.

Doing an explain analyze, this is the output:

```
Limit  (cost=1184359.89..1184384.89 rows=10000 width=95) (actual time=39395.145..39451.451 rows=10000 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=1184359.89..1186097.37 rows=694989 width=95) (actual time=39394.488..39449.924 rows=10000 loops=1)
        Sort Key: (min("timestamp")) DESC
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 3375kB
        ->  Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=856703.95..1134710.88 rows=694989 width=95) (actual time=30343.111..39339.675 rows=97445 loops=1)
              Group Key: evse_label, evc_model, address, city, message, reason
              ->  Gather Merge  (cost=856703.95..1096486.49 rows=1389978 width=95) (actual time=30343.062..39141.342 rows=231382 loops=1)
                    Workers Planned: 2
                    Workers Launched: 2
                    ->  Partial GroupAggregate  (cost=855703.92..935048.51 rows=694989 width=95) (actual time=29867.817..37735.438 rows=77127 loops=3)
                          Group Key: evse_label, evc_model, address, city, message, reason
                          ->  Sort  (cost=855703.92..862943.39 rows=2895788 width=79) (actual time=29867.788..35909.736 rows=2317226 loops=3)
                                Sort Key: evse_label, evc_model, address, city, message, reason
                                Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 215024kB
                                Worker 0:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 203704kB
                                Worker 1:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 219048kB
                                ->  Parallel Seq Scan on om_logbook_mart  (cost=0.00..287564.88 rows=2895788 width=79) (actual time=0.033..1852.787 rows=2317226 loops=3)
Planning Time: 1.285 ms
Execution Time: 39478.630 ms
```

Can you make me understand how to optimize it?

UPDATE: After setting work_mem to 500MB:

```
Limit  (cost=543440.12..543465.12 rows=10000 width=95) (actual time=6466.267..6468.723 rows=10000 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=543440.12..545184.77 rows=697860 width=95) (actual time=6466.265..6467.809 rows=10000 loops=1)
        Sort Key: (min("timestamp")) DESC
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 3646kB
        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=486607.40..493586.00 rows=697860 width=95) (actual time=6384.249..6425.960 rows=97403 loops=1)
              Group Key: evse_label, evc_model, address, city, message, reason
              Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 49169kB
              ->  Seq Scan on om_logbook_mart  (cost=0.00..329588.97 rows=6978597 width=79) (actual time=0.040..2362.520 rows=6978597 loops=1)
Planning Time: 0.135 ms
Execution Time: 6489.381 ms
```

Can i do something more?

Comment: `Sort Method: external merge  Disk:` is your enemy here. Got more memory?

Comment: work_mem is not set while the DB instance is a t3.medium with 4GB of RAM. Do I need to expand the RAM?

Comment: You could use SET work_mem TO '500MB'; for your current database connection. When this works fine, you can set this in your database configuration, or maybe on connection level. Depends on what you need. With just 4GB of memory, don't use a large setting, it might crash your query: out of memory

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/170860/how-to-optimize-min-max-queries-for-large-tables-on-postgresql  maybe this link can help you. can you also tell us what's the primary key.

Comment: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX user_to_hostgroup_pkey ON public.user_to_hostgroup USING btree (username)

Comment: Index sounds like useless for your query because there is no `WHERE` clause to filter rows, so the full table must be scanned in any case and the seq scan will be preferred by the planner.

Comment: after setting work_mem=500MB this is the new plan (updated my question)

Comment: What about making `public.om_logbook_mart` into a range partitioned table partitioned by `timestamp` column? If this table is large, it might be helpful to reduce table scanning size.

Comment: thanks for the response. It's my table too big for you (Row Count Estimate: 6.978.597; Disk Space: 2,3G). If yes, how can be partioned my table?